# KafkaProducers with DirectByteBuffer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, bytebuffer

In a memory intensive java application , having multiple KafkaProducer instances sending large json strings (1-1.5 MB) to KafkaBrokers configuring buffer.memory to a higher value (lets say 256 MB) triggers frequent GC's . I need large buffer to compensate for gap between high throughput of application generating messages and slow speed of KafkaProducer sending messages to KafkaBrokers . Is there a version of KafkaProducer library exist which uses direct buffer (off heap) instead of on heap buffers (ByteBuffer.allocate() call ) . Is it a reasonable solution to explore or there are other ways to improve upon the performance in case of large messages being sent to brokers ?

Comment: I think you can increase partition size from server.config file to better utilization of resources

Comment: Have you tried using compression? Or other, smaller formats than JSON like msgpack?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for sending DirectMemoryBuffer to Kafka producer?